# ArgumentError: Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method with the name as_passAString

Tags: ane

The ANE's C++ native-side code pulls in third-party libraries. I get an error when I run ANE. No error will be reported without using this third-party library.

ArgumentError: Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method with the name as_passAString.
at flash.external::ExtensionContext/_call()
at flash.external::ExtensionContext/call()
at MyANE/passString()[C:\zhangming\IntelliJ IDEA\projects\RealSenseANE\src\MyANE.as:19]
at Main/run()[C:\Users\colacowin\Desktop\Project\PPMAESTRO-3\src\Main.mxml:628]
at Main/___Main_Button21_click()[C:\Users\colacowin\Desktop\Project\PPMAESTRO-3\src\Main.mxml:1015]